# function addFunc at 0x10fae4f28

Tags: python, type-conversion

```py
import math
x = 4

firstFunc = (3 * x) -5

secFunc = 4 - math.pow(2, x)

print(firstFunc, secFunc)

def addFunc(x=4):
   result = firstFunc + secFunc
   print(result)

print(addFunc)
```

I'm doing math homework so I decided to add two of these functions by defining a function parameter as x = 4. But unfortunately I'm getting this output "function addFunc at 0x10fae4f28"

Comment: And, btw, `firstFunc = (3 * x) -5` is not defining a function, it assigning the value of `(3 * x) - 5` to variable `firstFunc`. The same applies to `secFunc`. I guess you need to convert the logic into real functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function like so:

```py
print(addFunc())
```

What you are seeing is where the function is stored in memory after the `def` statement has executed, since the function is an object